# How to not reset a variable each time the web page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, backend

i am trying to code a website that keeps track of a variable that changes value on everyones computer
i have tried local storage but it did it just localy and i don't know what to do.

Comment: you must directly initialize this value from the server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Yeah, you should probably have a database that holds this information. There are plenty of resources for saving data in a database. [MongoDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) is popular.

Comment: So you store the values somehow on the server. When the page is requested you read the value and put it into the document. The solution really depends on what your serverside set up is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would mainly be left to the backend and the database management system. The frontend should render the stock value it receives from your api. If someone purchases the goods or the shop owner adds goods, the value should be updated by the backend into the database which will send the correct data to your frontend in the next render

Answer (score 1):

You need something to persist your data. This could be a database e.g.
To access the database you could use a server side language, e.g. python.
So when the user visits you side, the actual information can be retrieved from  the "backend"

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can solve your issues in a couple of ways:

1. If you can obtain your datas from a public API or a webpage you can use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) directly in your webpage without creating a backend.
2. You can use something like [nodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [express](https://expressjs.com) to render a webpage on the server and ship it to the client with all the data updated.
3. You can write a backend (using something like [nodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [express](https://expressjs.com)) and a frontend that can fetch the datas from the backend.